# Vertical tangent to curve $x+y=e^{xy}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, implicit-differentiation

Find the point where the curve  $x+y=e^{xy}$ has vertical tangent.

That means $\frac{dx}{dy}=0$ at $(h,k)$

So differentiating given curve w.r.t $y$ both side we get

$$\frac{dx}{dy}+1=e^{xy}\left(x+y \frac{dx}{dy}\right)$$ putting $\frac{dx}{dy}=0$ we get

$$e^{hk}=\frac{1}{h} \tag{1} $$

Also $$h+k=e^{hk}=\frac{1}{h}$$

So $$k=\frac{1}{h}-h$$ substituting $k$  above in $(1)$ we get

$$e^{1-h^2}=\frac{1}{h}$$

that is $$eh= e^{h^2}$$

By guess $h=1$ but graph gives another solution , how can we reject that?

Comment: What do you mean by graph gives another solution? it seems correct to me

Comment: Why would you want to reject it? if you check that point, it still satisfies the equation you obtained and it is indeed a point where there is a vertical tangent (it's about $0.4508$)

Comment: My graphing calculator is giving that line $x=0.4507$ is cutting but not touching

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, you cannot reject the other solution, because it too yields a vertical tangent.

The numeric value of this solution is $$h \approx 0.45076365201730712954444197879707455059948938737236.$$

At this value, we find $$k \approx 1.7676938378993928727733449223485097251562623801697.$$

You may verify that $e^{hk} - 1/h \approx 0$ for this point, to the numerical precision given.

The graph of the relation $x + y = e^{xy}$ is shown below.  Note the obvious symmetry:

[image]

The graph also suggests that a coordinate transformation could shed more light on the function's behavior; i.e., let us perform the rotation $$(u,v) = \left(\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{y-x}{\sqrt{2}}\right).$$  This transforms $(x,y) = (1,0)$ to $(u,v) = (1/\sqrt{2}, -1/\sqrt{2})$; i.e., it performs a clockwise rotation of $\pi/4$ about the origin.  Then the implicit relation becomes $$e^{(u^2-v^2)/2} = u\sqrt{2},$$ which can be solved explicitly for $v$ to yield $$v = \pm g(u) = \pm \sqrt{u^2 - \log (2u^2)}, \quad u > 0.$$  This proves that the original curve has a slant asymptote where $x+y = 0$; it also shows that $g(u) \sim u$ as $u \to \infty$, since $u^2 \gg \log (2u^2)$.  But since $g(1) = \sqrt{1 - \log 2} < 1$, it also shows that $g$ must approach $u$ from below:  indeed, $$g'(u) = \frac{u^2-1}{u g(u)}$$ implies $g'(1) = 0$, and $g'(2) = 3/(2 \sqrt{4-3 \log 2}) > 1$, so by the intermediate value theorem, there is a $u \in (1,2)$ such that $g'(u) = 1$, corresponding to an $(x,y)$ for which $dx/dy = 0$.

Comment: Thanks can you please show the tangents also

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma Done.  If you find an answer to be satisfactory, please consider voting on it and/or accepting the answer.

Comment: Pretty clear now